# Leitura de arquivo.ini

Tags: c++, arquivo, ini

É possível fazer leituras de variáveis em `arquivos.ini` com C++?

Ex:

```
host = "localhost"
name = "username"
pass = "password"
port = 1010
```

Quando fizer a leitura a partir deste arquivo eu setar através do `ifstream`.

```
ifstream dados;
dados.open("arquivo.ini); 
while(getline(dados, linha)){
void sethost(linha){
this->host = linha;
}
}
```

Sendo que quero somente o valor de cada variável ex: de host eu quero `localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use uma [biblioteca pronta](https://github.com/brofield/simpleini) ou vai cometer muitos erros.

```
CSimpleIniA ini;
ini.SetUnicode();
ini.LoadFile("arquivos.ini");
const char * pVal = ini.GetValue("config", "host", NULL);
ini.SetValue("config", "host", "127.0.0.1");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Library/IniFile.cpp).